# Slideshow browse button doesn't work

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to setup a slideshow on my site using the Slideshow setup that is currently used on D7. I click on the Slideshow option and the following screen shows up. Then, I enter the name, and then I tried to browse the image. Somehow I can't seem to browse for the image (let alone attach it).

> [image]

Is there a reason why? Is there something that I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. There was a missing JS file. Installed the missing JS file and now it is working.